# Android Camera, fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera

I have **`3 fragments`** Tab Views in my app, each have different layout, `camera` is only working on the `first fragment` while the other 2 fragments are working properly but **`NOT turning on the flash like the first fragment`**. How could i release camera before switching to the other fragment? I am using

```
camera.release();
```

but it crashes my app.

Answer (score 0):

In which methods do you open and release the camera?

Most likely, you should release the camera in `onTabChanged()` callback as well as in `onPause()`.
Without more information (code of your Activity, crash stacktrace) it is hardly possible to give a good advice.

Comment: I am new in Android development 


    private void getCamera() {

        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera Error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

Comment: But from where do you call this `getCamera` method? And from which place do you call `camera.release()`? You may consult with this guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html